# Communication between Tcl scripts

Tags: tcl, exec, tk-toolkit

I was successfully able to redirect the standard output of a script called by my GUI (tcl/tk) using:
`exec [info nameofexecutable] jtag.tcl >@$file_id`

[Here's a description of my system.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9U9gT.png)
Now I want to be able to tell jtag.tcl to stop data acquisition (which is in an infinite loop) when I click "stop" button. Is it possible through `exec` or should I use `open` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `exec` command waits until the subprocess finishes before returning control to you at all (unless you run totally disconnected in the background). To maintain control you need to open a pipeline:

```
# Not a read pipe since output is redirected
set pipe [open |[list [info nameofexecutable] jtag.tcl >@$file_id] "w"]
```

You also need to ensure that the other process listens for when the pipe is closed or have some other protocol for telling the other end to finish. The easiest mechanism to do that is for the remote end to put the pipe (which is its `stdin`) into non-blocking mode and to check periodically for a quit message.

```
# Putting the pipe into nonblocking mode
fconfigure stdin -blocking 0
```

```
# Testing for a quit message; put this in somewhere it can be called periodically
if {[gets stdin] eq "quit"} {
    exit
}
```

Then the shutdown protocol for the subprocess becomes this *in the parent process*:

```
puts $pipe "quit"
close $pipe
```

Alternatively, kill the subprocess and pick up the results:

```
exec kill [pid $pipe]
# Need the catch; this will throw an error otherwise because of the signal
catch {close $pipe}
```

Comment: I just tried it and it is working great. Thank you for the great explanations and examples.
To be perfect, I would need the subprocess to signal the parent process when it can safely close the pipe. 
In other words, the subprocess receives the 'quit' keyword, finish the current transaction with the hardware (if any), and tells the parent process to close the pipe. I guess there is going to be a conflict since the subprocess output is redirected to the text file.